# Inserting data into a table from itself and from another table mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables:

`table1` contains `roleid`

`table2` contains `stringtext`,`table1_roleid` (which is a FK to the roleid field in table1)

`table2` now contains 5 entries, each with the same `table1_roleid` value and different `stringtext` values, I want to replicate the `stringtext` values in the same table but with a different `table1_roleid` value that I want to fetch from `table1`.

To explain further here's a representation:

```
table1
+--------+
| Roleid |
+--------+
| 1      |
| 2      |
| 3      |
+--------+

table2
+------------+---------------+
| stringtext | table1_roleid |
+------------+---------------+
| text1      |             1 |
| text2      |             1 |
| text3      |             1 |
| text4      |             1 |
| text5      |             1 |
+------------+---------------+
```

End result for table2 should be:

```
table2
+------------+---------------+
| stringtext | table1_roleid |
+------------+---------------+
| text1      |             1 |
| text2      |             1 |
| text3      |             1 |
| text4      |             1 |
| text5      |             1 |
| text1      |             2 |
| text2      |             2 |
| text3      |             2 |
| text4      |             2 |
| text5      |             2 |
| text1      |             3 |
| text2      |             3 |
| text3      |             3 |
| text4      |             3 |
| text5      |             3 |
+------------+---------------+
```

I thought of creating a temporary table copying `table2` and each time I can update the `table1_roleid` in the temp table but I'm after a smarter method where I can put in a loop for example and insert into the same table without having a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all the rows you want with a `cross join`.  Because the result will already contain some rows in `table2`, you need to filter them out.  Here is one way:

```
insert into table2(string_text, table1_roleid)
    select t2.string_text, t1.roleid
    from table2 t2 cross join
         table1 t1
    where t1.roleid <> 1;
```

A more general way would change the `where` clause to:

```
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table tt2
                      where tt2.string_text = t2.string_text and
                            tt2.table1_roleid = t1.roleid
                     )
```

Comment: I didn't know about cross join. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is just create a cartesian plan between the two tables. Is the same as the `cross join`

```
Insert into table2 (string_text, table1_roleid)
  select t2.stringtext, t1.Roleid 
    from table1 t1,
         table2 t2
   where t1.Roleid <> 1
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7fc3/1

What it do is combine every registry from the specified tables except (or only) those registries that fit the conditions.